# Image resizing shows Poor Quality?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I have image and while re-sizing it gets Poor Quality

[image]

My code:

```
string sFile = "D:\\Testing\\" + txtnewname.Text;
Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(Convert.ToInt32(txtwidth.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtHeight.Text));
newImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
{
    gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    gr.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, (Convert.ToInt32(txtwidth.Text)), Convert.ToInt32(txtHeight.Text)));
}
newImage.Save(sFile + ".jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Did you mess something up with your screenshots? I wouldn't describe a completely white picture (your "after" picture appears as blank to me) as "Poor Quality"?

Comment: Did you try saving in a lossless format? Perhaps its the jpeg compression step and not the resizing that decreases quality.

Comment: You should really show images for a question like this...

Comment: Firstly try to save to PNG(lossless format) and compare quality. Secondly check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484759/quality-of-a-saved-jpg-in-c-sharp

Comment: i put the images somebody is edited my ques ..sorry for the inconvinence

Comment: Same Image Quality COmes,.... !

Comment: Is your source image a CMYK jpeg file?

Comment: @ Dlemsta it RGB only....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446834/how-to-detect-if-a-jpeg-contains-cmyk-color-profile   i tried this...it shows RGB

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not with the saved quality, IMO its quite fine. The problem is different aspect ratio that you are saving new image to. Thats why it looks of different quality than original image.

You must make sure that the new image persists the original image's aspect ratio by enforcing it. Whatever height or width you provide as input, one of them must be automatically set to retain original aspect ratio.

```
Bitmap originalImage = Bitmap.FromFile(oFile) as Bitmap;
double ar = (double)originalImage.Height/originalImage.Width;
int newHeight = 100;
int newWidth = (int)(newHeight/ar );
Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
//and then do what you want to do
```

Comment: @AravindSrinivas, can u send me image file ... see this http://www.fileconvoy.com/

Comment: also what height and width?

Comment: i changed default height...but quality is same